# Error en la vista de diseño de un Activity Main Drawer

Tags: android-drawerlayout

tengo el siguiente error en la vista de diseño de un activity main drawer, cuando ejecuto la aplicacion en el emulador no me da ningún problema y la barra de desplazamiento me la enseña perfectamente pero en la vista de diseño no me la enseña correctamente.

Os pongo una imagen de como me muestra la vista de diseño y el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_calcula"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exposure_black_24dp"
        android:title="News" />
    <item
         android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Calcula" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Calendari" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Conveni" />
</group>

<item
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el error ocurre porque no encuentra el NavigationView, tienes que importarlo en tu clase principal de esta manera:

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
```

Editado:

Si no te ha funcionado lo anterior prueba a cambiar la targetSdkVersion en el gradle, seguramente la tendrás en 27, bájala a 26 y comprueba si te ha solucionado el problema.

Comment: Cuando añado  "import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;" a la clase principal me saca un error y me pide que optimize la importacion y me la convierte a "import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;" pero la vista de diseño continua igual. La implementacion del Gradle tampoco consigue solucionarlo.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta añadiendo otra posible solución, espero que te sirva. Cuando lo pruebes cuéntame si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Te comento, cuando añado "import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;" a la clase principal me pide que la optimice, después de optimizar me la convierte a "import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;" pero no me soluciona el problema.

Comment: Intuyo que el error se debe a una de las últimas actualizaciones del Android Studio, por que en las pruebas en la creación de otros ejemplos con Navigation Drawer realizadas meses antes de estas actualizaciones no tengo ningún problema en la vista de diseño del activity_main_drawer, incluso los ejemplos que creé meses antes ahora me los visualiza bién y si creo el ejemplo ahora me lo visualiza incorrectamente.

Gracias por tu ayuda, continuaré investigando que crea este error en la vista de diseño.

Comment: ¿Has probado lo último que te he dicho, cambiar el targetSdkVersion en el gradle? Si lo has probado ¿te sigue mostrando el mismo error? Y si después de hacer eso sigue el problema, tengo una duda respecto a lo que has comentado, cuando cambias la forma de importar el NavigationView te ¿sigue mostrando el mismo error? Porque en la imagen muestra un error con "android.support.design.widget.NavigationView", por lo que si cambias la forma de importarlo te tendría que mostrar un error distinto o no mostrarte el aviso.

Comment: Si he probado cambiar el targetSdkVersion en el gradle y me sigue mostrando el mismo error y continua el mismo problema, y cuando optimiza la forma de importar el  "import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;" en la clase principal me  la convierte a "import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;" y el error es el mismo.

Comment: Mira esto, creo que por ahí van los tiros...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882191/rendering-problems-could-not-find-android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout

Comment: Según eso es solo un problema en el editor y seguramente para tu caso ocurra lo mismo, pero también pone que cambiando el nivel de la api podrías ver la vista previa, que te sería muy útil para facilitarte el diseño, prueba a cambiarlo por si te funciona, y si no simplemente edita solo con el texto, porque tu aplicación funcionará bien aunque te muestre ese aviso.

Comment: Bajar el nivel de la API no funciona.